# Pytest passes when run in debug mode but fails otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pytest

Following is the pytest code that I execute to test the add connection command.

```
 def test_cli_connection_add(self, cmd, expected_output, expected_conn):
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(connections, cmd)
        assert result.output.strip() == expected_output
```

It fails with issue that tells the expected output should have newline.

```
>       assert result.output.strip() == expected_output
E       AssertionError: assert ('Successfully added `conn_id`=new4 : '\n 'hive_metastore://airflow:******@host:9083/airflow') == ('Successfully added `conn_id`=new4 :   \n'\n 'hive_metastore://airflow:******@host:9083/airflow')
E         + Successfully added `conn_id`=new4 : hive_metastore://airflow:******@host:9083/airflow
E         - Successfully added `conn_id`=new4 :
E         - hive_metastore://airflow:******@host:9083/airflow

tests/cli/commands/test_connection.py:558: AssertionError
```

To debug this issue further I added set_trace in the code:

```
 def test_cli_connection_add(self, cmd, expected_output, expected_conn):
        pytest.set_trace()
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(connections, cmd)
        assert result.output.strip() == expected_output
```

When I execute the code via debugger, the assertion pass. Can anyone help me why this works this way?

Comment: It looks like there is an extra new line in the actual output. It could be occurring just random and likely not have anything to do with pytest. You can try removing all new lines in both expected and actual output